# Unable to push in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push a counter in the second column of an array but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?
My problem is in the function **"matchKeywords"** and specifically the line **"`arrayToMatch[i].push(counter);`"**.

This is the error I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: arrayToMatch[i].push is not a function
at matchKeywords ((index):54)
at window.onload ((index):73)
```

Here is my code:

```
var arrayOfKeywords = ['USA Canada UK Australia Japan India', 'USA Canada UK India UK Australia China Brazil France', 'Brazil France Australia China'];
var oneWord = [[]];
var twoWords = [[]];
var threeWords = [[]];
var ArrayOneWords = arrayOfKeywords.join(" ").split(" ");

for(i = 2; i < ArrayOneWords.length -1; i++){
    //Create array twoWords
    twoWords.push(ArrayOneWords[i-2] + " " + ArrayOneWords[i-1]);
  //Create array threeWords
    threeWords.push(ArrayOneWords[i-2] + " " + ArrayOneWords[i-1] + " " + ArrayOneWords[i]);  
}

function matchKeywords(arraySource, arrayToMatch){
var counter = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < arrayToMatch.length; i++){
    counter = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < arraySource.length; j++){
        if (arraySource[j].indexOf(arrayToMatch[i]) >= 0){
        counter++;
        }
    }
    arrayToMatch[i].push(counter);
    }
}

//Remove duplicate
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}

oneWord = unique(oneWord);
twoWords = unique(twoWords);
threeWords = unique(threeWords);

console.table(matchKeywords(arrayOfKeywords, twoWords));
```

Comment: This `twoWords.push(ArrayOneWords[i-2] + " " + ArrayOneWords[i-1]);` is pushing Strings and not objects with a function `push` or an array instead.

Comment: It's my goal and it's working. It's not the problem I have for now. Do you mean I need to push a place holder?

Comment: I don't know what your logic does, but that push with strings is the reason of that error.

Comment: I Think I understand, so how I can push [[ArrayOneWords[i-2] + " " + ArrayOneWords[i-1] [0]]? If that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that within the `matchKeywords()` function, you're treating `arrayToPush` as jagged array (an array of arrays) - but the array you're passing into the function (`twoWords`) is just a regular single-dimensional array.

You've initially defined it as `var twoWords = [[]];` which does, indeed, create a jagged array, but the call to `twoWords = unique(twoWords);` turns it into a single-dimensional array.

That's why you see the error message "`arrayToMatch[i].push is not a function`" - because what's now being stored at `arrayToMatch[i]` is no longer an array -- because of the call to `unique()`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting error because you have defined `var twoWords = [[]];`. So `twoWords` is multi dimensional array but having only one array inside it.  So in case of `twoWords[1]` it will be `undefined`.

Update `matchKeywords` function as below. Added one line `arrayToMatch[i] = arrayToMatch[i] || [];`.

```
function matchKeywords(arraySource, arrayToMatch) {
    var counter = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < arrayToMatch.length; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < arraySource.length; j++){
            if (arraySource[j].indexOf(arrayToMatch[i]) >= 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        arrayToMatch[i] = arrayToMatch[i] || [];
        arrayToMatch[i].push(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I get this error now "(index):40 Uncaught ReferenceError: twoWordsi is not defined at window.onload ((index):40)". From what I understand from the other comments it's more about dealing with multi array, so whenever I push I have to specify the exact location, but I can't with my limited knowledge.